# Decrypting Base64 encoded string with AES results in error status 4301 (buffer too small)

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, ios7, commoncrypto

I would like to decrypt a `AES` encrypted string which is `Base64` encoded in Objective-C:

This is my code:

```
NSString *base64String = @"RwH0KBSRjFKJQYGsCze0";
NSData *base64Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:
     base64String options:0];

char * key = "shouldbe16chars.";
NSUInteger dataLength = [base64Data length];
uint8_t unencryptedData[dataLength + kCCKeySizeAES128];
size_t unencryptedLength;

CCCryptorStatus status = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,
    0 , key,kCCKeySizeAES128, NULL, [base64Data bytes], 
    [base64Data length], unencryptedData, dataLength, 
    &unencryptedLength);

NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:
     unencryptedData length:unencryptedLength 
     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"status: %d output: %@",status, output);
```

When running the code, the result is: `Status = -4301, output = null`

According to the documentation, **Status 4301 = "buffer too small"**

When debugging my code, variables are set as follows:

```
base64Data = 4701f428 14918c52 894181ac 0b37b4
dataLength = 15 bytes
unencryptedLength = 0
unencryptedData = {}
```

The error occurs only when the option `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` is set, if it set to `0`, status = 0, output = {}.

I have checked many code samples on SO but do not find anything wrong with my code.

Do you have any idea on what could be wrong with my code?

BTW: The `base64string` I am using in this sample code has been created in JavaScript using this open source framework: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html. I do not know if this information helps.

Comment: Off the top of my head - make sure they are both in the same mode of operation (looks like CTR on the JavaScript page).

Comment: @RoboticCat: Where can I find more information on CTR? CTR is new stuff to me :-)

Comment: Mode of operation is the way encrypted blocks are linked together.  You need to check the Apple docs to find out what options to set.  You will also need to check if padding is being used on the JavaScript side and then set the appropriate option in iOS. Basically, you need to use exactly the same IV, Key, Mode, Character set and padding on each side.  The following link may help (hopefully): http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564

Comment: When you use padding, the plaintext message is extended to the next block boundary.  You need to ensure that your buffer has enough space to accept both the message *and* the padding.

Comment: @rossum: How do I do that? :-)

Comment: An AES block is 128 bits (=16 bytes).  Calculate the number of complete blocks in your message and add one: buffer_bytes = 16 * (1 + (plaintext_bytes / 16)).

Comment: Isn't this line taking care of this issue? `NSUInteger dataLength = [base64Data length];uint8_t unencryptedData[dataLength + kCCKeySizeAES128];`?

Comment: No, use the block size: `uint8_t unencryptedData[dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128];` which is the same size but use the correct enum.

Answer (score 1):

Your second-to-last argument in CCCrypt should be dataOutAvailable. You pass dataLength, which seems to be the length of the inData (which you have already, correctly, passed as an argument).